# How does time warp at the midpoint between 2 equal mass black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon, estimation

Assuming large masses and 1km between event horizons.

Is time very slowed? or what?

I am making a video game that is approximating relativistic effects on time near massive bodies. I am not concerned with things like spin and complex orbits, or other messy real world details. I just want to know if I should add relativistic effects together between massive bodies, or if they cancel out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Binary black hole systems are complicated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_black_hole